# Angular material slider with ticks

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I am implementing angular material slider. I need the ticks to show in any way possible. As implemented there is seems to be one tick html tag that's building but it's not rounded dots that I need.

What it currently looks like:
[image: this is what it looks like]

What I want the slider to look like:
[image: this is what I need it to look like]

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="mat-slider-ticks-container" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="transform: translateX(-1.05708%);">
    <div class="mat-slider-ticks" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-size: 2.11416% 2px; transform: translateZ(0px) translateX(1.05708%);">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider added an example of your code so we can identify the problem. Also check [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow/help/mcve) to read what your question should look like ideally.

Comment: <mat-slider *ngIf="showFilter[i]" tickInterval="auto" step="10" thumbLabel min="1" max="100"></mat-slider> . this is the angular code i have the above is the code that is generated

Comment: It does seem to insert ticks as shown on their documentation site. Seems like a styling issue. What css do you have to style these ticks like you want?

Comment: I actually installed it with custom css options so yes, there is no css for it, so that's a question how to style it? Is there an example, because when I try all I see is one line no dots.

Comment: have a look https://stackblitz.com/angular/eneoeoxjlae?file=app%2Fslider-configurable-example.ts

Comment: thank you, looks like it s background image with repeating linear gradient so they are always these little black dots :( and not at all what I need on top image. Thank you.